# Vite environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, vite

The doc says:

```
To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only variables prefixed with VITE_ are exposed to your Vite-processed code
```

How does one use a variable not prefixed with VITE_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the idea is to copy the non-vite env variable to the prefixed one:

`VITE_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME vite build`.

If you have too many, you may want to consider using a .env logic instead.